# Why does PHP think that an uploaded PHP script in the $_FILES array is a "text/plain" file?

Tags: php, file-upload

Surprised to find the `type` attribute an uploaded `.php` file in my web application is listed as `text/plain`. Should `.php` files not have a `application/x-httpd-php` mime type?

I want to be able to restrict PHP scripts from being uploaded, but i obviously dont want that to result in text files from being being restricted also.

Comment: The browser decides the MIME type to assign to uploaded files. It may not have an association for `.php` so defaults to plain text.

Comment: @Barmar so is it better just to check if the filename ends in `.php` rather than rely on the `type` attribute?

Comment: You can use the `mime_content_type()` function. It checks the contents to see if it looks like a PHP script.

Comment: @Barmar the environment this runs on however is < PHP8.0 so dont have that luxury. Might have to stick to checking the file extension

Comment: You could also check whether the file contains `<?php`.